# Transactions are not rollbacking in quartz when spring @Transactional is used

Tags: java, spring, transactions, quartz-scheduler

I am using `@Transactional` annotation and inside it doing Quartz scheduling (used `JobStoreCMT` Jobstore specified in quartz.properties file) if any exception thrown after `scheduleJob()` method then it doesn't delete rows from JobDetails and JobTrigger Table of Quartz as those jobs are not triggered yet.

I want Job and Triggers details to be deleted from table when some exception is thrown after `scheduleJob`.

@Transactional

void rollback() ..

1. called quartz scheduler
2. throw Exception